# Value of *ip printed as the address of the variable it is pointing to

Tags: c, pointers

For the code below

```
int main()
{
  int x = 2;
  int *ip = &x;
  printf("%d",*ip); // Printing the value of *ip gives 2
                    //Now if the value of ip is incremented
  ip++;
  printf("%d",*ip); //Printing the value of *ip gives the incremented memory         
}
```

Can someone please explain as how the value of `*ip` is getting printed as the incremented memory location. `*ip` being the deferencing operator should return the value at the address right?

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and see if that's helpful.

Comment: Did you mean to do `(*ip)++`? I assume you'd want to increment `x` through your pointer, rather than increment your pointer.

Comment: int *ip = x actually means, declare ip as a pointer to int and assign the values of x (which is as int) to ip (which is a pointer to int)

Comment: Yes, looks like it should be `int *ip = &x;`

Comment: Hi there was a mistake in posting the question.. it should be &x not x

Answer (score 5):

I see two things wrong with the code. One is the line:

```
int *ip = x;
```

This attempts to assign the value of an int to a pointer. This can be forced with compiler flags, but should give an error. Nevertheless, I suspect this may be a typo in your question, since dereferencing an address of 2 should almost certainly crash, but you've claimed it ran and produced an output of 2. I'm going to assume you actually have:

```
int *ip = &x;
```

The second problem is:

```
ip++;
```

Here you are incrementing the pointer, rather than the int it points to. I think what you intended (to increment 2 to 3) would be:

```
(*ip)++;
```

That is, increment the value the pointer points to.

If you increment the pointer, it will now point to somewhere else on your stack, which could be another local variable (like the pointer itself), or the return address, or the stack frame pointer, or some other hidden value. There is a good chance the new value will be some sort of pointer which a value similar to the address of your pointer, or will otherwise look like the output of printing a pointer. Naturally, you should not be incrementing a pointer that points to a single element. It's never a good idea.

Comment: Hi, for the first part I am sorry the question was mistakenly printed, it should be &x not x, thanks for the correction. For the second which you have mentioned, *ip++ is also possible like (*ip)++, the question is of associativity. For (*ip)++ there is no problem because the value contained in the memory location (as pointed by ip) is incremented. I tried with *ip++ to see the results and found that, this time the value printed is the incremented memory location, however there was no value at that location. In short the pointer ip was pointing to an uninitialised integer location

Answer (score 2):

This code may behave unpredictably, because

```
int *ip = x;
```

assigns the value of x, to a pointer.
Basically it hard codes 2 into the pointer ip.

It may compile with warnings.
It may later lead to memory errors at run time.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for this glitch, I have corrected the line it is &x not x, can you please now look at the question

Comment: Yes, that fixes the first issue. It still has the 2nd issue as explained by Daniel Stevens. The code is incrementing  ip and it now points to a location on stack that the code itself did not allocate. Hence it prints whatever happens to be there, which is an unpredictable behavior.